# SAS EG lagcalculation issue, not calculating las as t - t-1

Tags: sas

can some one resolve the issue there:

```
data want;
 set have;
 by mac;

 if first.mac then do; DayDif=0; KmDif=0; end; 
       else do;
          DayDif = Date - lag(Date); /* calculate the difference between two dates */
          KmDiff = Kms - lag(Kms);
      end;
run;
```

And what I got result is as (0 in first line but . in second):

```
Mac          Date   Kms           DayDif    KmDif
SP0001      10DEC07 1885462.00000   0        0
SP0001      12DEC07 1885462.00000   .        .
SP0001      30APR09 1885462.00000   505      0
SP0001      15JUL09 1886577.00000   76       1115
SP0001      16JUL09 1887667.00000   1        1090
SP0001      17JUL09 1889181.00000   1        1514
SP0001      17JUL09 1888825.00000   0       -356

.
.
```

(here When machine changed, lag is taken as t - (t-2) and not as t - (t-1) ) why???? something wrong in the code ??

```
   Machine  Date    Kms          DayDif KmDif
   SP0001   01OCT14 2898108.00000   1   1059
   SP0001   02OCT14 2899148.00000   1   1040
   HP0001   03OCT14 2900334.00000   1   1186
   HP0002   17JAN08 926384.00000    0   0
   HP0002   18JAN08 926384.00000    -2450   -1973950
   HP0002   28APR09 1237332.00000   466 310948
   HP0002   29APR09 1238599.00000   1   1267
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it this way...

```
data want;
 set have;
    by mac;
      RETAIN lag_date lag_kms;
      DROP   lag_date lag_kms; 
       if first.Mac
          then do; 
                  DayDif=0;
                  KmDif=0;
          end; 
          else do;
              DayDif = abs(Date - lag_date);
              KmDif = abs(Kms - lag_kms);
      end;
      lag_date = Date;
      lag_kms = Kms;
run;
```

Which was giving me the result I wanted..

```
Mac             Date    Kms        DayDif   KmDif
SP0001  10DEC07 1885462.00000   0         0
SP0001  12DEC07 1885462.00000   2         0
SP0001  30APR09 1885462.00000   505       0
SP0001  15JUL09 1886577.00000   76        1115
SP0001  16JUL09 1887667.00000   1         1090
SP0001  17JUL09 1888825.00000   1         1158
SP0001  17JUL09 1889181.00000   0         356
```

But Now I need to do one more thing...
Total = 1158 + 356 for 17JUL09 and so forth. i.e. add a column in which we will have cummulative sum values grouped by Date.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Look into DIF() function as well. It operates the same way but calculates the difference directly.

Comment: @Reeza thanks for suggestion, I already tried it and finally the above solution, as wrote, works fine for the data I have. :)

Answer (score 3):

The values for the `lag()` function are not taken from the previous observation (a common misconception).. *They are stored in memory every time the function is executed* (see [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212547.htm)).

In your example, when the machine changes, the lag function is not executed due to the conditional logic  (`if first.mac then do / else`) - so the "t-2" value is simply the result from the previous iteration.  Try the following:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by mac;
  if first.mac then do; 
    DayDif=lag(Date); /* executing the lag for subsequent iteration */
    DayDif=0; 
    KmDif=0; 
  end; 
  else do;
    DayDif = Date - lag(Date); /* calculate the difference between two dates */
    KmDiff = Kms - lag(Kms);
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @RawFocus for your help and suggestions.