# If condition is not executed when the first condition is verified SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

The following code is executed and the result is wrong.
When the first condition is verified the code don't work correctly.
The lag1 it remains as missing when the value should be 3...
Thanks for help me.

```
DATA VALUES;
INPUT VAL caract$ var1 var2;
DATALINES;
1 a 12 0
1 c 0 4
1 c 3 2
2 a 3 2
2 b 15 16
2 b 4 1
3 a 12 13
3 c 12 13
4 c 14 15
5 b 14 0
6 b 14 15
7 a 12 15
7 c 12 15
8 c 14 15
9 c 14 5
10 c 13 7
;
RUN;

%macro lag_var(dataset, lag);

data &dataset&lag;
    set &dataset;
    by VAL;

       %do i=0 %to &lag;
       if caract eq 'b' then
         lag&i=lag&i(var1);
       else lag&i = lag&i(var2);
       %end;

    if first.VAL then do;
       count=0;
       %do i=1 %to &lag;
        lag&i=.;
       %end;
    end;

    count+1;

   %do i=1 %to &lag;
       if (not first.VAL and count<=&i) then do;
               lag&i=.;           
       end;
   %end;

   maxi = max(of lag1 - lag&lag);
  run;
%mend lag_var;

%lag_var(VALUES,3);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS EG lagcalculation issue, not calculating las as t - t-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485127/sas-eg-lagcalculation-issue-not-calculating-las-as-t-t-1)

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by "remains as missing". What exactly was your code supposed to do, and what exactly is happening? Also, read here on [how to ask good questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to write a minimal, working, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surely related to conditional execution of the LAG function.  Try changing to something like this using TEMP1 and TEMP2 variables to hold the lagged values.

```
%do i=0 %to &lag;
  temp1=lag&i(var1);
  temp2=lag&i(var2);
   if caract eq 'b' then
     lag&i=temp1;
   else lag&i = temp2;
   %end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.